# Yum install sort of not working

Tags: centos, software-installation, virtualbox, yum

so I'm not too familiar with this stuff, but when I try:
yum install VirtualBox-6.1
it returned no package available, I tried some of the fixes suggested by others but no luck
next I tried:
yum install VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.26_145957_el7-1.x86_64.rpm
which worked. (this was also suggested, but without any explanation)
I was wondering if anyone knew potentially why this is the case. Again, I'm not too familiar with this stuff so any explanation welcome. If it matters this was on centos.

Comment: Did you download the .rpm manually?

Comment: @cutrightjm yes, for clarification, I was following instructions given to me, which inclines me to believe that it should or has worked in the past on the same setup

Comment: If I had to guess, the instructions meant to say VirtualBox-6.1*, where the * is a wildcard. For whatever reason, it was either missing or tried to render as some type of markup

Comment: If you downloaded the package from Oracle https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.26/VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.26_145957_el7-1.x86_64.rpm , then the full package name must be used : `VirtualBox-6.1-6.1.26_145957_el7-1.x86_64.rpm` . ....... If you install from a repo, e.g. rpmfusion-free, the package name is VirtualBox : `yum install VirtualBox` ........ which you can check beforehand with `yum search virtualbox`

Comment: alright, thanks for the explanations, in that case it probably is just a problem with the instructions as they specified to download the .rpm package from Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `yum install package`, `yum(8)` consults the current list of packages in the configured repositories (downloading a fresh copý if needed) and uses that to check for the exact package version (and any dependencies, and does the whole dependency management dance). If there is no `package` in the currently configured/consulted repositories, the answer is as you state.

If you have a file `package-<version>-<rpmversion>.rpm`, running `yum install package-<version>-<rpmversion>.rpm` will (try to) install that RPM, handling dependencies through the repositories as above. Running `yum install package-<version>` if that isn't in the repositories, there won't be a match in the database, and the install fails. That there is a file `package-<version>-<rpmversion>.rpm` around doesn't matter, it won't be considered.

Comment: I see, thanks for the detailed explanation!